# Angular select default on lazy loaded items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i have the following controller:

```
    app.controller('ProfileController', ['$http','$sessionStorage','api', '$scope','Session', function ($http,$sessionStorage, api, $scope, $state, Session) {

    $scope.titles = {};
    $scope.selected_title = $sessionStorage.activeUser.user.title.id;

    $http.get(api.getUrl('title',null))
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.titles = response;
        });

}]);
```

Now with this i have the following select:

```
<select ng-init="selected_title.id" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in titles"></select>
```

However since the options of the select is loaded using http then it will be loaded after the page has loaded therefore the default value is nothing.

Can anyone tell me how i might avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngInit` doesn't work that way, it is not a default value.

```
    app.controller('ProfileController', ['$http','$sessionStorage','api', '$scope','Session', function ($http,$sessionStorage, api, $scope, $state, Session) {

    $scope.titles = [];

    $http.get(api.getUrl('title',null))
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.titles = response;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                 if (response[i].id == $sessionStorage.activeUser.user.title.id) {
                      $scope.selectedItem = response[i];
                      break;
                 }
            }
        });

}]);
```

And remove `ngInit` from your select.

[Documentation for ngInit.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: this did not work sadly :s However i can see that it says the value but the select itself doesnt show the selected value

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Yes, I didn't consider that both objects were not equals even if the had the same content. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the title when the data has come back:

```
app.controller('ProfileController', ['$http','$sessionStorage','api', '$scope','Session', function ($http,$sessionStorage, api, $scope, $state, Session) {

  $scope.titles = {};
  $scope.selected_title = $sessionStorage.activeUser.user.title.id;

  $http.get(api.getUrl('title',null))
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.titles = response;
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.titles[0];
  });
}]);
```